# 0 as first number in Vue model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am trying to put in a Dutch `phoneNumber` field in a form. But when I put in the first digit 0 it gets removed when I put in the second.

Dutch phonenumber: 06 + 8 digits (0612345678) or 0 + 2 digits (region code) + 7 digits (012 1234567) or 316 + 8 digits (31612345678).

```
<el-input
 v-model.number="form.phoneNumber"
 @keypress="isPhoneNumber(form.phoneNumber)"
 :placeholder="$t('phonenumber')"
></el-input>
```

with this as validator:

```
phoneNumber: [
 {
   required: true,
   type: "text",
   pattern: "^(?:0|(?:\+|00) ?31 ?06 ? )(?:(?:[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){8})|(?:6 ?-? ?[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){7})|(?:[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]\d ?-? ?[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){6})|(?:[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]\d{2} ?-? ?[1-9] ?(?:[0-9] ?){5}))$",
   message: this.$t("please_fill_a_phonenumber"),
   trigger: "blur",
 },
],
```

Is there something obvious that I overlook?

Comment: You're using a numeric input field (`v-model.number`). Numbers don't have leading zeros.

Comment: ^^ what Robby said: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model: *"`.number` - cast valid input string to numbers"* Phone numbers aren't numbers (despite the word "number" in the name).

Answer (score 1):

Kindly, visit Official Vue.js Docs on [How to Form Input Bindings?](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#number) to find out the right way how to use the `v-model` directive and the modifiers. Because you're using a `.number` modifier. Also, visit Element Library's Official docs [element.eleme.io](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form) that how to use `el-form` and `el-input` elements.